# Python split array and check the 0 index if the same and join it

Tags: python, list

I have an array looks like:

```
['varyasyon__in=27', 'varyasyon__in=25', 'varyasyon__in=1']
```

and I want to split every value on `=` and join it to be a string like:

```
varyasyon__in=27,25,1
```

Comment: how did you get the array? this smells like XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ['varyasyon__in=27', 'varyasyon__in=25', 'varyasyon__in=1']
data = {}
for i in a:
    key, val = i.split('=')
    try:
        data[key].append(val)
    except KeyError:
        data[key] = [val]
for i, j in data.items():
    print(f"{i}={','.join(j)}")

varyasyon__in=27,25,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
f"varyasyon__in={','.join([val.split('=')[1] for val in data])}"
```

Output:

```
varyasyon__in=27,25,1
```

Comment: it's not always varyasyon__in it changes but it's still the same shape {key}={value}

Answer (score 0):

Сommon solution with dictionary:

```py
lst = ['varyasyon__in=27', 'varyasyon__in=25', 'varyasyon__in=1']

d = {}
for i in lst:
    d.setdefault(i.split('=')[0], set()).add(i.split('=')[1])
    
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'varyasyon__in': {'27', '25', '1'}}
```